# Thermostat bypass wiring

Tags: voltage, heat, 433mhz

I'm trying to bypass the heaters thermostat of my apartment and having only a small knowledge of electronics I would like to have a some help with it.

**Forgive me for the ugly paint schema** but I preferred to show you the schema with the modules I will really be using because it's on 230V and I wouldn't want to mess it up.

[image: my ugly wiring]
 -  What would you recommend as a 5v power source ?

- What about my electronic choices ?
- Is my wiring correct ?

Electronics that I will be buying:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-Solid-State-Relay-SSR-25DA-25A-250V-3-32VDC-/350684034969

http://www.ebay.fr/itm/433MHz-Wireless-Transmitter-and-Receiver-Modules-MX-FS-03V-MX-05-/140928401303

Excuse my bad english.

[edit]
Here's how I see it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKMTvG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The thermostat will be all the time to the max temp because it doesn't regulate at all, it only turns the heater on if the temp is lower than the one chosen.

Comment: That kind of receiver won't work, in the absense of an RF carrier (transmitter operating) they will output random noise and it'll be switching on and off all the time.

Comment: If you have a "small knowledge of electronics" it's not a good idea to tamper with mains related devices, especially related to control circuits.

Comment: @alexan_e I agree. Especially because the thermostats I've seen are not directly mains powered, but the schematics show this as such.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to achive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **What would you recommend as a 5v power source ?**

A battery (4 or 5 x AA?) and a voltage regulator.

It really depends what sort of thermostat (24 V DC, 230 V AC?), availablity of a mains outlet near the thermostat, power consumption of modules (inc SSR in both states), frequency of use (active listening state) and how often you are willing to swap batteries.

> **What about my electronic choices ?**

So far as I can see, they don't yet form a coherent whole.

> **Is my wiring correct ?**

No. At least I very much doubt it.

The output from your wireless module appears to be a TTL level serial output (RX). This won't be suitable for directly connecting to a solid-state-relay as it will contain a series of on-off pulses representing data.

You appear to want a module with a simple latched on/off output. [like this?](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/rf-receiver4-toggle)

> These Simple RF receivers are the easiest way possible to add wireless control, painlessly! There's no programming, configuring or addressing - simply power the receiver with 5-10VDC and press the buttons on our matching RF keyfob remote. When the A button is pressed, it activates the first pin, when the B button is pressed, it activates the second one, and so forth for all four buttons. There's no microcontroller required, its just a simple one-to-one link.
>
> The T4 toggle type acts like an alternating toggle switch - when the A button is pressed the first time, the matching pin goes high. When the A button is pressed a second time, the matching pin goes low. The pins are turned on and off by repeated presses

You may instead want a small microprocessor to receive RX from your existing module and toggle the SSR state based on the content of received message packets.

Since your diagram is primarily visual rather than conceptual I can't tell whether the connections to the thermostat will kill you, set your home on fire, blow a fuse or work as expected. A schematic is a much better way to communicate the necessary information (press Ctrl+M whilst editing your question).

---

Sorry to be so gloomy. I suggest you temporarily put this project to one side and construct a system to wirelessly turn a small benign LED on and off (rather than a potentially lethal 230 V AC heating system). Once you have that working you will be better able to revive the heating controller project. Nil desperandum.

---

Update:

Your new schematic shows your SSR providing power to the thermostat, I assume that's something similar to a typical [Honeywell T6360](http://www.honeywelluk.com/products/Temperature-Controls/Temperature-OnOff-Control/T6360-Room-Thermostat/) 230V thermostat. In that case you are not completely bypassing the thermostat, you are able to turn off heating when the timer/controller and thermostat would otherwise be calling for heat. You are not able to turn on heating when the thermostat thinks it isn't needed. That may be what you want. The connections should be safe so long as you use the right gauge wire, with adequate insulation and protection (in conduit or back box), make good connections etc.

Comment: Thank you, it will all be controlled remotely as an on/off switch so I guess that 4 AA will be enough.
Don't worry I wasn't going to do it without testing before.

Comment: Yes, I didn't explained it well the thermostat will still be used but I will turn it to max when I want to use my relay.
Now I'm trying to find a receiver that could turn it on or off

Answer (score 1):

The RF transmitter and receiver are intended for low speed data transmission. This means you need to: -

1. Design a transmit frame consisting of preamble, data and checksum
2. Program a MCU to transmit this data to the transmitter
3. Have a 2nd MCU that can receive data from your receiver
4. Program second MCU so that it recognizes the preamble then the data and checks the validity of the data against the checksum - this is to avoid other unwanted transmissions being recognized as potentially valid data. (433MHz is used by many devices).
5. Once the data is receiver you then output a signal to turn on your device (or turn it off)

Here is a picture that might help you understand what the receiver will be outputting with and without a proper data transmission sent to it: -

[image]

I think this is a slot bigger project than what you envisaged. Also, as mentioned in other answers/comments it's best to start by using a simple LED rather than potentially electrocute yourself or damage the receiver with inappropriate wiring.

Comment: Couldn't it be an easier way to do it ? I'm just trying control it as a on/off switch wirelessly

Comment: There are chips you can buy that interface to the transmitter and receiver that would save you programming MCUs but I don't know how good they are at resisting transmissions from other 433MHz users in the vicinity. Using radio comes with a price.

Comment: +1. Where's that picture taken from?

Comment: @m.Alin it's a picture I drew in word to show that an FM receiver is generating all sorts of noise until a carrier comes along - it can apply to AM systems too if you regard the noise as what you might see if the AGC is flat out trying to find a transmission.

Comment: Impressive drawing skills!